# Enum save failing, error message not displayed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, enums, data-annotations

I am new to MVC.  I have defined an enum for `UnitOfMeasure` in my Ingredient table, as follows:

```
public enum UnitOfMeasure
{
    oz=1,
    lb=2,
    ml=3,
    liter=4,
    gal=5
}
```

I have defined the corresponding field as follows:

```
[Required]
[Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please make a selection")]
public UnitOfMeasure? UnitOfMeasure { get; set; }
```

"Please select", as desired, is displayed as the default value in the view, but I want the user to have to make a selection before the save.  I am using `EnumDropDownListFor` as follows in the view.

```
 @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.UnitOfMeasure,
                              "--Please select--", 
                              new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Two problems. First, the error message is not appearing when the user doesn't make a selection, and second, I cannot save any selection at all (apparently no selection matches the range criterion).  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remove the `[Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please make a selection")]` attribute. All that is needed is your `[Required]` attribute (and add the `ErrorMessage` in that attribute. And have you included `@ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UnitOfMeasure)` in order to display the message?

Comment: That fixed it!  Thanks Stephen!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the form is not submitting, but no error message is displayed, it means that you have not included the placeholder for the message. You need to include

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UnitOfMeasure)
```

The `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` plugin parses the `data-val-*` attributes in the html generated by your `EnumDropDownListFor()` method, and add the rules to `jquery.validate.js`, including passing the element that acts as the placeholder for the message. In you case, there is none, so nothing can be displayed, but the form is invalid and is not submitted.

Note that you `[Range]` attribute is unnecessary since the `[Required]` attribute already means that you must select one of the `enum` values. You can simply use

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please make a selection")]
public UnitOfMeasure? UnitOfMeasure { get; set; }
```